# TensorFlow serving: get input shape and labels

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow-serving

I'm am currently trying to set up a TensorFlow Serving client that has the task of working through a queue of messages of the following format:

```
{
  "model_url":"http://path/to/some/model",
  "image_url":"http://path/to/some/image"
}
```

In other words, each message says which image should be predicted on using which model. Ideally, I should not have to specify any further information within the queue in order for this to work.

There are two problems though. The size of the input image could vary, whereas the expected input size is fixed (determined by the model). So the client must version resize the image. For that, it must know what the expected input size is.

**So my concrete question is**: if I know `model_url`, is there a way to make a request to the TensorFlow Serving server so that it tells me what the expected input shape looks like? Similary, I would need to know the labels that are associated with the predictions that the model delivers (e.g. "cat", "dog" etc. if we were doing image classification).

What I am looking for would be along the lines of the following pseudo code:

```
request_dict =    {
  "meta_info":["input_shape", "labels"]
}

response = requests.post(model_url, data=json.dumps(request_dict))

input_shape = response["input_shape"]
labels = response["labels"]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can request all shapes of the inputs and outputs from your model by sending a request to the `/metadata` path of your TF server.

In its most simple form:

```
import requests
metadata_url = f'http://{host}:{port}/v1/models/{modelname}/metadata'
response = request.get(metadata_url).json()
```

The response will be a dictionary that contains the full signaturedef specification of your model (i.e., the shapes of all inputs and outputs).

This is probably easiest if using the REST api. See https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/api_rest for more examples (under 'metadata API'). Also know that it's possible to expose ports for gRPC traffic (for actual payload traffic) as well as for HTTP traffic (to request the model metadata) at the same time. Just specify both ports when running the server.

Comment: If anyone is confused about where to find the actual dimensions, they'll be here (but could vary depending on signature) `response["metadata"]["signature_def"]["signature_def"]["predict"]["inputs"][input_name]["tensor_shape"]["dim"]`

Comment: Yeah, it's an ugly mess. But the information is there :)